# How to make contextual inference succeed for the return type of previously declared function in a generic variadic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCmAuGBvGoCuZkCc0xsBbAIyXxgF8YBeDLEXAtABhoG4BYAKD9CRYAcyRQAyvBJJ6MADwAVAHwAKCFNQwFASjQL6SuBp69B0GPjHZ8YcVEQyGK7Qbj3kJvgBMkwADbwljAAZrjAUACW4FiWDuJIfr5QIPhy4n4RwEgQMEgAHshgXjm4ANZgIADuYADaALoANDAAqqoAdB2BwhBoNR1tohIZWT2MNREwEWAwpUgAniDBMOmZ2XVozq4rI+N1NE0ADvggAFZJKRv9XaPb2S50hs11ujAqV-jdaGUV1fX3j55TOBzAA3QIReBeTK3CAAdQiUAAFgBhcDIArYeB+ACSYGClCQYCysmAsWQ8US4RSKksUGstncSCaXlcXm0JjMsGQ0AAjLIwfgIVDgDD4UjUXh8nSsbj8ZYiUg1IztG0cJL8IDOTABULocNsmKUWipZicXiCQqAPLBADihMomRJZKQFPO+BpVhsdgcTUUqi8ehe+geMDZJgA9OGYIBeDcA4juTc3y4nBeARPwQJo6yF61ZwhFGyUYmWJwlZa12sAO4BKhwuCIlMDlKpgATArnZKAAJn54OzIv1efFxqLZrlpaQ5ftgurCGQKrVBE1be1veFovzEvR0tHFrLwQAIr4ApYvAAxaYMUlIOIJN0eulexlNQaSaTsviRmPxqZjhUhVPppmq45iMhqbiaxa-nuh7+IESBnmANZzpMDZNtUrZCDA3JQAAzD2gp9uuQ6Ftusq7hOB5HnBCFIUg87MOqgKfgAQtgsAREs2KhlRQTwCEYSRNEEAHL4HGOsEKQwOAMgAEQQPqMlNEihIJlBMiVCkpQ5EcIAifgfhzN4PEyKERKCdMV43pSyT4Jala3IoTStG8nQfKMNQvvqlyuZ8MDfM2fyuAohzHGcVKEK87y+TUCjPK4TwvC5bTXF8jY-LUcUhs0S6YdJtxOte5K3uFdkuvq970t6yDPmIr50Ryy7YQALLIeXlbOdGqgxi58EAA)

I have a case where contextual inference fails for a previously declared generic function. I don't understand why it fails but providing a function without generic arguments is contextually inferred successfully.

I have the restriction that the argument `projector` must come last. This is to type the `createSelector` function of NgRx: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3268.

```js
const state: { counter: number } = { counter: 0 };

const getSame = <T>(same: T): T => same;
const returnState = () => state;

declare function createSelector<Slices extends unknown[], U>(...args: [...getSlices: { [i in keyof Slices]: () => Slices[i] }, projector: (...args: Slices) => U]): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

const variadicSlicesWithContextualInference = createSelector(returnState, d => d);
const test1 = variadicSlicesWithContextualInference(state).counter;

const variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfGeneric = createSelector(returnState, <T>(d: T): T => d);
//  inference fails, variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfGeneric(state) is unknown
const test2 = variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfGeneric(state).counter;

const variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn = createSelector(returnState, getSame);
//  inference fails, variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn(state) is unknown
const test3 = variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn(state).counter;

// But if I declare a function specific for one "slice", then inference works properly
declare function createSelectorOneSlice<T, U>(...args: [getSlice: (...args: unknown[]) => T, projector: (...args: [T]) => U]): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

const oneSlice = createSelectorOneSlice(returnState, getSame);
const test4 = oneSlice(state).counter;
```

Comment: What is `test2` supposed to show?  It's not using `variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfGeneric`.  TypeScript doesn't have a full unification algorithm for its inference, so higher order type juggling like this isn't guaranteed to work.  The compiler is better with rest elements at the end, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAvA1W); does that work for you?  Although, as asked, your question is "why does this happen" so maybe you're not interested in workarounds...

Comment: Thanks for finding that error. I have updated `test2` to use that function. It appears that fails to infer, which means TS fails to infer `T` for some reason.
Looking at your solution, it appears using a tuple type for `args` is my problem. Unfortunately, I'm looking for a solve that retains the tuple type, as it's required to achieve the argument typing for `createSelector` I need for https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3268

Comment: Is your primary question "why doesn't this work" or is it "how can I get it to work"?  If it's the latter then someone answering should spend the bulk of their time trying to get a working version of that signature; if it's the former, then they should spend it trying to identify and explain how the TS heuristic inference algorithm fails to behave as desired.

Comment: I want the contextual inference to work, so I have updated my question title.

Comment: I've also added the restriction that `projector` must come last in the function arguments, to maintain the current API of `createSelector`.

Comment: The more I look at this the more I suspect this is just not possible variadically; presumable a list of overloads of varying lengths wouldn't suffice here?  Generally speaking though the compiler can't guarantee that it will specialize a generic function into the "correct" monomorphic version this way... so you could always call `createSelector<[typeof state], typeof state>(returnState, getSame)` if you have to.  Maybe a set of fixed-length overloads followed by a variadic one?

Comment: A workaround like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyO9JN) could be your best bet, maybe?  It depends on the use cases I guess.  Let me know if that's good enough for you, and if not, [edit] the example code to demonstrate the unsatisfied cases.

Comment: I would prefer to not write explicit overrides since they are more effort to maintain. But I will have to use that approach if contextual inference is not possible for a function in a generic argument in a variadic tuple type.
I have no edit to make bc the unsatisfied cases are "infinite", given enough arguments are provided to `createSelector`.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: (Note: you mean "overloads" and not "overrides".)  I find it hard to believe that you need to support someone calling `createSelector()` with such a large number of generic arguments that it would blow out the list of overloads.  Remember, if you pass in non-generic "slice-getter" functions, you won't have a problem.  If your objection is difficulty of maintenance, can you demonstrate that?  In any case, since you say "I will have to use that approach if...", does that mean I can post it as an answer and you may accept it if no other approach is found?

Comment: Given there is not another solution, then someone with the same problem as me should declare overloads for now. I'm writing up an issue in TS to see if this is a design limitation or not. So I'll accept that answer.
The maintenance of the function signatures is probably not a high cost. I personally wish generic tuple types comprehensively solved the need to declare repetitious overload signatures.

Comment: I've added my issue to the TS repo- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion here is that this is not currently possible in TypeScript. The inference algorithm is not "full unification" as requested/discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134); instead it is more heuristic in nature and, while it often does what people want, has limitations.

You're using [leading elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) here, which seems to be complicating things.  If you were able to re-order the parameters so that the variadic part came at the end (like a well-behaved [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) should):

```
declare function createSelector<S extends unknown[], U>(...args: [
    projector: (...args: S) => U,
    ...getSlices: { [I in keyof S]: () => S[I] }
]): (...args: unknown[]) => U;
```

or equivalently

```
declare function createSelector<S extends unknown[], U>(
    projector: (...args: S) => U,
    ...getSlices: { [I in keyof S]: () => S[I] }
): (...args: unknown[]) => U;
```

then things would probably work better:

```
const variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn = createSelector(getSame, returnState);
variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn(state).counter; // okay
```

Unfortunately you can't do this.

---

Since your variadic version works just fine for non-generic `getSlices` elements, I think your best bet would be a hybrid approach where you declare a series of [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) call signatures for some non-variadic `getSlices` sizes, to capture the most likely use cases.

When developers call `createSelector()`, how many parameters do they typically pass?  Probably just a few.  So you can deal with those few to get the desired inference, and then fall back to the variadic version:

```
// 0
declare function createSelector<U>(
  projector: () => U): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

// 1
declare function createSelector<A, U>(
  getSliceA: () => A, 
projector: (a: A) => U): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

// 2
declare function createSelector<A, B, U>(
  getSliceA: () => A, 
  getSliceB: () => B, 
projector: (a: A, b: B) => U): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

// 3
declare function createSelector<A, B, C, U>(
  getSliceA: () => A, 
  getSliceB: () => B, 
  getSliceC: () => C, 
projector: (a: A, b: B, c: C) => U): (...args: unknown[]) => U;

// n
declare function createSelector<S extends unknown[], U>(...args: [
    ...getSlices: { [I in keyof S]: () => S[I] },
    projector: (...args: S) => U]
): (...args: unknown[]) => U;
```

and this also works:

```
const variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn = createSelector(returnState, getSame);
variadicSlicesWithContextualInferenceOfDeclaredFn(state).counter; // okay
```

So, hooray!

---

Overloads do have drawbacks; for example, when you're not directly calling the overloaded function, but instead trying to have the compiler *infer* something about the type of an overloaded function, it tends to just ignore all but the first or the last call signature, which can be confusing and surprising. (See the documentation for [inferring in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) where it talks about overloads).  And in this case the overloads will be redundant and more annoying to maintain.  But if you care about callers having their generic `getSlice` elements inferred properly, overloads are the best way I can think of to get that to happen.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlCB7ATgEwppA3gLABQS5S86wUALknSLRAFyGXoCuwzmbwnMACM8SAL5IAvOyrdebAAziA3KVIUONegHMItAMrhk0gDwAVAHwAKKEbZmAlPakWGR1WQpUtSTHs6YwPq0TMZIVg4uDCHMHhoA9ABU6hS48AA2IH5IAGbc8LQAltSUfqH6EOkQBVgm+kgQAB7MwNhQSNwA1sDoAO7AANoAugA0SACq1jCY6ABW1bRYbFYAdGtZ2lBs+pGSruMjKRrkayu6BumFiFvsAwCSSIXASJ0QAJ7oOUj6Q8u7rvp7kNxEckE5wqcNjcuj1+sN-hM4hREvE1J5yGlMtk8sACsVnvAyswKlUapg6g1mhBWu0YX1BqMJtZIZhNmwBqCNNM5gslhD1qybjsogdORRTud9JdrmwCEh7o9nq8Pl8fn8ooC7sCxKChuDVgK2R1gN16fCRR40RpvHQkAA3LKFEDYK5Sq7QADqhVoAAsAMLUZjNTggdJ3YA5PDUxAAeRyABFqliINgAGLPaSEiDlSq8zBWSVGMZ+WgBIIxCAOJHkB2YJ0u+Bu65e30BnhNUuh8ORvy4iBxxMZLIp9M2CsOFayduYZRIeLxJDoTogN5onUkUigSCwBDIGN2vDpdDO9rEDfozS2xjMWUcOR4fiCET4CTSOVT+RIJRiS0Xm06PRDEgKQkHMaxbEgexwTMKIIIgatL3oEsy2CUIQIiWCK1-DRMWHXJ8iKEosxzUlFnJSYrG5eYyXVPYJn1FkjTpOE9QtUFcOxAj8VKbNiVzMkTAAQTGCjJWlCBBNo1xhKQKi82WEA2EEhFxgYw1oRNWEGRUhCOOQHE8SIokIBJPMhLGAAhETrDE91JPCBEZNsxALKkpArNkmZqLIhSlLGIQ2AslS1JWKE2GY7S2IvPT8NxQiCWM0yBJkjy-WsgtAPE+yMLopzMvdVyHKiDznIgP03LSzyeRo8JFKQGSAvcsZ4DYP1guWRiNNNFidNBJJEiQZ1sEG9owBAYA3hGpAPk4ABybJLledJJsWJBgAgFMkF9Qp2h9QptB9UQsFwfAnh7aN9KwMZxuG31qVyUN0iQIQEE6Lb0C2w6kF0dbMFDSgQCgVhEhRdikzwgz4p4kizPqDtqTaY1uoZdLOvZMUTjWUqbjlBUnhed5Pm+X4irozVtUOC8uS8+T+VCwVthUoZQRCsKka0806PGbCvGoW1a3rV1xKgFt-UDDsQzDCMoz7Adwb8NMM2hvjSKwKxkMCVDmDGQtICrUEBedIX3RF70xfbYMu2l3tYwTeWR2AMdQgnD88FnedF2XVdzzEIA)